# Create an array of items pulled from an array of dicts?

Tags: python, arrays

I have some output data in this format:

```
[{'state': 'OK', 'sname': 'sig1', 'extra': None}, {'state': 'OFF', 'sname': 'sig2', 'extra': None}, {'state': 'OK', 'sname': 'sig3', 'extra': None}, {'state': 'UNKNOWN', 'sname': 'sig4', 'extra': None}]
```

This data can contain any number of entries. What I want to do is pull out all the `sname` values into a list like this:

```
snames = ['sig1','sig2','sig3','sig4']
```

How can I iterate over the output without knowing its length in advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to do this:

```
In [1]: array_of_dicts = [{'state': 'OK', 'sname': 'sig1', 'extra': None}, {'state': 'OFF', 'sname': 'sig2', 'extra': None}, {'state': 'OK', 'sname': 'sig3', 'extra': None}, {'state': 'UNKNOWN', 'sname': 'sig4', 'extra': None}]

In [2]: snames = [d['sname'] for d in array_of_dicts]

In [3]: print snames
['sig1', 'sig2', 'sig3', 'sig4']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension.

With

```
my_dict_list = [{'state': 'OK', 'sname': 'sig1', 'extra': None}, {'state': 'OFF', 'sname': 'sig2', 'extra': None}, {'state': 'OK', 'sname': 'sig3', 'extra': None}, {'state': 'UNKNOWN', 'sname': 'sig4', 'extra': None}]
```

You can get all `'sname'` entries via:

```
my_list = [x['sname'] for x in my_dict_list]
```

and

```
print(my_list)
```

prints

```
['sig1', 'sig2', 'sig3', 'sig4']
```

Answer (score 2):

The shortest and most pythonic is to use a list comprehension :

```
data =  [{'state': 'OK', 'sname': 'sig1', 'extra': None}, {'state': 'OFF', 'sname': 'sig2', 'extra': None}, {'state': 'OK', 'sname': 'sig3', 'extra': None}, {'state': 'UNKNOWN', 'sname': 'sig4', 'extra': None}]

snames = [i['sname'] for i in data if 'sname' in i]

print(snames)
>>> ['sig1', 'sig2', 'sig3', 'sig4']
```

It's better to verify that 'sname' is in your dict or you might get a `KeyError` unless you are sure about their consistency (you could get rid of `if 'sname' in i` in that case).

Comment: I would only start checking if I know that there are some dictionaries in the list that don't contain the Key. Otherwise potential unwanted errors in the nested data structure may not be detected. But I guess that heavily depends on the problem.

Comment: You're right, I had it "just in case" guessing that if we are not sure about the length, it could also be uncertain regarding the dicts. I added a precision in my answer.